# How to serve webp from a different folder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, webp

I have a folder /assets/admin/images/products which contains .jpg and .png files and another folder /assets/admin/images/products/webp with the webp version of .jpg and .png files with name filename.webp (jpg and png is not added in file names)

How do i serve webp version of image from different folder using htaccess

I found some information at https://github.com/vincentorback/WebP-images-with-htaccess but it only serves from same folder.

I tried below htaccess code, but it didn't work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webp/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webp/$1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vage. I could _guess_ that what you are trying to ask is how you can rewrite a request for an image to a png/jpg version in that other folder if no webp version exists? If so, just add another `RewriteRule` below the current implementation that rewrites the request to that other folder. That's all.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear. What i am trying to do is, i have png and jpg images in a folder and by default website is loading images from this folder. A new folder is added with same images but in webp format. I am looking for .htaccess code which loads webp images from second folder on supported browsers.

Comment: And that is what I answered to in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good but you don't need `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` on the last line with `RewriteRule`. This is the problem.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/webp/$1.webp -f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ webp/$1.webp [T=image/webp,E=REQUEST_image]
```